# Create simple grob layout

Tags: r, gridextra

I'm trying to make an R script for printing (drawing) text on PowerBI.
I want a layout like :

```
[1,1,1,1]
[2,2,3,3]
```

1,2 and 3 would be a textGrob

I'm getting errors for creating a layout as soon as I don't use common plots. Or trying to change an example.

R

```
gs <- lapply(1:3, function(ii) 
  grobTree(
    rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=ii, alpha=0.5)), 
    textGrob(ii)
    )
  )

lay <- rbind(c(1,1,1,1),
             c(2,2,3,3)
             )
grid.arrange(grobs = gs, layout_matrix = lay)
```

Result :
[image]

This is from a more complex example on internet.
I'd like to do so without function, just writing my grobs and keep the grid.arrange as this matrixc layout...